# Regular expression in eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse

new here.  I have 4300 instances of:

```
 <c:out value="${crane_error.aac}" />
```

I want to replace with

${crane_error.aac}

Not sure how to format this in the find/replace box in eclipse

Thanx

Comment: Regexps here in so simple case is evil :)

Answer (score 3):

Search expression should look like this:

```
<c:out value="\$\{crane_error.aac\}" />
```

Replace expression should look like this:

```
\$\{crane_error.aac\}
```

**EDIT:** To match any variable you can use the following expression:

```
<c:out value="(\$\{[^\}]+\})" />
```

And the just replace it with:

```
$1
```

Comment: Thanx for the prompt reply.  The  variables are different accross the board.  I just used an example so it would be :

Answer (score 1):

With crtl-f you get the find/replace dialog. You don't even need regex for that, you can just copy your values in to the relevant boxes.

**edit:**

In that case you want to use regexp like this:

Find: `<c:out value=\"\$\{(.*)\}\" />`

Replace with: `\${$1}`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just used that as an example I need

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, that is an example.  I need ${whatever is here} to be what is replaced so           <c:out value="${whatever is here}" />  be replaced with   ${whatevere is here}

Answer (score 0):

In your file press ctrl+f, then search box is appear. In the there is find box insert your search string and there is a replace box, insert there your which you want to replace. then click on "replace All".

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>
- Without any regexps
- Just replace  your string to ${crane_error.aac}

### You don`t need regexps here.